# How can I let jprofiler find the PID of running tomcat server?

Tags: linux, tomcat, jprofiler

I extracted the jprofiler tar.gz on a remote linux server. After trying the bin/jpenable command I got:

```
'No unprofiled JVMs found.'
```

So I went looking for the PID of the running tomcat server and I think I found it in the var/run directory. A file called tomcat7.pid
So I went back to the source folder of jprofiler and tried: jpenable --pid=[the id that was in the pid file I mentioned earlier]
as specified on page 277 of the following document: http://resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/help.pdf and got:

`No JVM with PID [the pid] found that is running as the same user.`

So since the user I'm logged in as is ubuntu I tried to log in with user tomcat7 but even after giving up the correct password (which we changed with sudo) I remain logged in as ubuntu (as confirmed by whoami command) and the problem above persists.

How do I get this jprofiler to find the jvm I need it to??

Comment: Is your Tomcat maybe configured to use a different TEMP directory?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.
We run tomcat as a service so we needed to add agentpath on startup of the jvm. Added the following to /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/setenv.sh :

```
-agentpath:/opt/jprofiler/jprofiler7/bin/linux-x64/libjprofilerti.so=port={port we want}
```

Then enabled that port on aws.